# How do you set a directory's default file?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, directory, defaults

Can I configure one specific directory on my webserver to use an atypical default file such as "default.php" instead of "index.php"? Do I have to create a ".htaccess" file in that dir?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, put the following in a .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex default.php
```

And that will apply to that directory, and I think all subdirectories.

This assumes you're using Apache; other webservers may have other conventions.

Comment: How do I set it not to apply to subdirectories?

Comment: You don't, as far as I know.  You need to put in separate .htaccess files for the subdirectories.